# Error with importing scikit-learn

Tags: python, pip, scikit-learn, canopy

I am trying to utilize the following code:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
import numpy as np
```

I get this error:

```
ImportError: No module named sklearn.datasets
```

I then try to install `scikit-learn`, but get these errors:

```
pip install -U scikit-learn
  File "<ipython-input-9-6d283b29f0f9>", line 1
    pip install -U scikit-learn
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax


easy_install -U scikit-learn
  File "<ipython-input-10-59440c1e5ef6>", line 1
    easy_install -U scikit-learn
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I am using Enthought Canopy Expresss which I thought "The Enthought Python Distribution already ships a recent version." as per http://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html#enthought-python-distribution

How can I use `scikit-learn`?

**Edit:**

After installing `pip` via `easy_install pip` I then tried running `pip install -U scikit-learn` and I get these errors (from my log file):

```
running build_clib

No module named msvccompiler in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils

customize MSVCCompiler

Missing compiler_cxx fix for MSVCCompiler

customize MSVCCompiler using build_clib

building 'libsvm-skl' library

compiling C sources

Partial import of sklearn during the build process.

C:\Users\cle1394\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:564: UserWarning: Specified path C:\Users\vagrant\src\master-env\libs is invalid.

  warnings.warn('Specified path %s is invalid.' % d)

C:\Users\cle1394\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:564: UserWarning: Specified path C:\Users\vagrant\src\master-env\include is invalid.

  warnings.warn('Specified path %s is invalid.' % d)

C:\Users\cle1394\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1494: UserWarning:

    Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.

    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the

    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting

    the ATLAS environment variable.

  warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)

C:\Users\cle1394\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1503: UserWarning:

    Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.

    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the

    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting

    the BLAS environment variable.

  warnings.warn(BlasNotFoundError.__doc__)

C:\Users\cle1394\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1506: UserWarning:

    Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.

    Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the

    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting

    the BLAS_SRC environment variable.

  warnings.warn(BlasSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)

sklearn\svm\setup.py:58: UserWarning:

    Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.

    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the

    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting

    the BLAS environment variable.

  warnings.warn(BlasNotFoundError.__doc__)

sklearn\setup.py:77: UserWarning:

    Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.

    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the

    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting

    the BLAS environment variable.

  warnings.warn(BlasNotFoundError.__doc__)

error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

----------------------------------------

Cleaning up...

  Removing temporary dir c:\users\cle1394\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_cle1394...
Command C:\Users\cle1394\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\Scripts\python.exe -c "import setuptools;__file__='c:\\users\\cle1394\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip_build_cle1394\\scikit-learn\\setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\cle1394\appdata\local\temp\pip-1ysfly-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed failed with error code 1 in c:\users\cle1394\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_cle1394\scikit-learn

Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\cle1394\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\pip-1.4.1-py2.7.egg\pip\basecommand.py", line 134, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Users\cle1394\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\pip-1.4.1-py2.7.egg\pip\commands\install.py", line 241, in run
    requirement_set.install(install_options, global_options, root=options.root_path)
  File "C:\Users\cle1394\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\pip-1.4.1-py2.7.egg\pip\req.py", line 1298, in install
    requirement.install(install_options, global_options, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\cle1394\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\pip-1.4.1-py2.7.egg\pip\req.py", line 625, in install
    cwd=self.source_dir, filter_stdout=self._filter_install, show_stdout=False)
  File "C:\Users\cle1394\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\pip-1.4.1-py2.7.egg\pip\util.py", line 670, in call_subprocess
    % (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd))
InstallationError: Command C:\Users\cle1394\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\Scripts\python.exe -c "import setuptools;__file__='c:\\users\\cle1394\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip_build_cle1394\\scikit-learn\\setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\cle1394\appdata\local\temp\pip-1ysfly-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed failed with error code 1 in c:\users\cle1394\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_cle1394\scikit-learn
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer for me was to install this http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scikit-learn for my specific version of Python.

Answer (score 9):

I guess you are trying to put these commands into your Python command line. They are supposed to work in your OS terminal.

Comment: I am on Windows.  You mean to say I need to open a command prompt and run these commands?  Does it matter what directory?

Comment: Yes, this is what I mean. It doesn't matter which directory.

Answer (score 4):

1. Scikit-learn is included in Canopy Basic (not Express)
   https://support.enthought.com/entries/22447950-scikit-learn
   https://www.enthought.com/products/canopy/package-index/
2. But you can install any package from the **OS command line** (as @sashkello points out, **not** python command line) as described here:
   https://support.enthought.com/entries/23389761-Installing-packages-into-Canopy-Python-from-the-command-line
   But depending on your OS and experience level, you may find this difficult because the package is not pure Python.

Comment: When I type `sys.prefix` in command prompt it reads `c:\\users\\dom\\appdata\\local\\enthought\\canopy\\user` but when I then try `easy_install pip` it says `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` and points to the last `p` in `easy_install pip`.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @user1477388: as Sashkello said, and Jonathan put in bold (!), you're typing the command into the Python console.  You have to run this in the shell instead.

Comment: @DSM I ran that command into command prompt i.e. when I go to run and type `cmd`.

Comment: @user1477388: no, `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` is a Python error message, not a shell error message.  So either you typed it into Python or you gave us the wrong error message.

Comment: @DSM Thanks, sorry I was typing `python` in CMD which was starting python.  Anyway, I installed `pip` however, I get an error when trying to install `scikit-learn`.  I posted the relevant log in my edit to the question.

Comment: @user1477388 The second error you have has been discussed many times before. Search for "error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat" and you'll see there are lots of answers for that.